# how to represent disabled cells into a table with alternate row color

Tags: tables, html, css, data-tables, disable

I'm creating an editable html table with alternate row color with a focused row highlighting .

When a cell is clicked, the user can modify its content.

Considering all of these, I need to indicate to the user that specific cells are desactivated and so not clickable.

I tried the basic "grey" background-color, but it cumulates 3 different shades of greys :

- the alternative row grey color
- the highlighting grey color
- the disabled cell grey color

and the result, is a little bit disappointing :
[image]

I tried another way, with stripped cell background :
[image]

None of them convince me enough, so what is the best way to represent disabled cells into a table using alternate row color ?

**EDIT**

Following the comments on the first answer, I'm trying the icon solution too
[image]

Comment: this is worth a look: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/to-use-or-not-to-use-zebra-stripes-or-alternating-row-colors-for-tables - not an answer, but maybe removing the striping should be considered, see the second answer

Comment: that icon is immediately much clearer

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be **not to use colour**. In fact colour is not necessarily the best way to do it as it relies a lot on good eyesight (which designers usually have, don't forget).

Here are some alternate ideas and ways of emphasising disabled state without using colour - these are suggestions, doing all would probably be overkill and observing users interacting with prototypes would be a good way of assessing different ideas (Hallway Testing is a good thing for this):

Change the hover state. Don't use a `cursor: pointer` hover style for example, leave the icon as a standard mouse cursor so nothing happens to it on hovering over the cell. Consider adding an edit icon that appears on hover of an editable cell too. Then a 'not editable' icon could appear on hover of a disabled cell.

Don't style links the links either - if you cells are interactive any text may (or should) have a typical link style. This can be removed, along with any hover state, for the inactive cells.

Consider a tool tip explanation. This would give the user feedback if they attempted to interact (which users will do to find out why). This could be on click, and should be on tap to help with touch screens without hover state.

You could use borders and font weight / style too. These would provide contrast between enabled and disabled. This is a bit like the link styling.

Also, provide a key outside the table, two cells, one styled enabled and one disabled with the works inside to help the user. These could be the point at which you explain why if the reason is common across the table.

Comment: in my special case, disabled cells must remain empty. so I cannot use font-weight / decoration for disabled content. And I'm not sure about the cursor trick, cause it lets the user discovering which cells are disabled by travelling hover all the cells

Comment: @PEC If they are empty, does that mean you can put anything in the contents? In that case, you could fill them with some short explanatory text (something like "(not editable)" or whatever suits your precise application), written in a distinguishable font.

Comment: @yo' I agree, I'm just afraid about the overload of unnecessary text on my table, maybe a small icon or something similar.

Comment: @PEC If a small icon, I would make it either "forbidden icon" (O slash) or a slashed pencil (which incidentally looks almost like an X mark)

Comment: @yo' I add an icon proposal inside the question

Comment: @PEC - specifically the cursor thing would be differentiating between hovering over an enabled cell and a disabled cell - there's a lot you can do with this

Comment: @ToniLeigh I don't like the cursor idea, cause the user will not be informed before hovering a specific disabled cell and on a touch screen, nothing will informs the user that he cannot touch (click) the cell.

Comment: @PEC that's one I wouldn't necessarily use just on it's own - if the user is already floating around / tapping on stuff then it would provide useful feedback, for highlighting enabled as well as disabled - it's also the sort of little detail that a bit of user testing would help greatly with